# Android SQL Access Best Way

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have db file in my resource ( for example in assets or raw )

1) I can access this db file with **SQLiteOpenHelper**?

2) And when my app check the new version if possible, downloading new db and copy the ( assets or raw ) folder

How do you think I should do?

***Sory for my bad english and thank you much***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best that you move the file to either internal or external storage, simply because both R.raw and the assets folder are read only.

You will never be able to download an update to your database into raw or assets, so even if the first database can be read from there, all subsequent updates will have to be on more accessible storage.

Comment: Moreover, `SQLiteDatabase` needs a local file, so even if you wanted to access the database read-only, you would still need a file, not just a stream from a raw resource or asset.